# Cucumber-boilerplate error running

Tags: javascript, cucumber, autotest

I am looking for simple setup for doing auto testing js with cucumber,
I find some nice package webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate, but looks like it isn't working for me have some errors like:

```
Uncaught Error: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

All what I did is copying this test folder and added dep to package.
Maybe you can suggest some nice package with simple setup and examples?

Comment: Did you download `chromedriver` from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and put it in PATH?

Comment: added and run this but getting Uncaught RuntimeError
     (UnknownError:13) An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Problem: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I install [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/) and set path for 
And after I install [selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone) set up the url and port of selenium from config all works for me.